# Wordpress 3.4 PHP code in menu links

Tags: php, wordpress, menu, blogs

I'd like to add PHP code to some links of my WordPress blog menu.
I use

```
Dashboard > Appearance > Menus
```

to make up the menu.
And it seems if I add PHP code there, it doesn't work.

I need the link like:

```
<a href="http://domain.com/signup.php?user=<?PHP code goes here?>&session=2">
```

Is there any way to add PHP code there and keep the built-in WordPress method of menu generation?

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need to set up a Custom Walker for that. Just add this in your functions.php file:

```
class Query_Nav extends Walker_Nav_Menu
{
    function start_el( &$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0 ) {
        global $wp_query;
        $indent = ( $depth ) ? str_repeat( "\t", $depth ) : '';

        $class_names = $value = '';

        $classes = empty( $item->classes ) ? array() : (array) $item->classes;
        $classes[] = 'menu-item-' . $item->ID;

        $class_names = join( ' ', apply_filters( 'nav_menu_css_class', array_filter( $classes ), $item, $args ) );
        $class_names = $class_names ? ' class="' . esc_attr( $class_names ) . '"' : '';

        $id = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_item_id', 'menu-item-'. $item->ID, $item, $args );
        $id = $id ? ' id="' . esc_attr( $id ) . '"' : '';

        $output .= $indent . '<li' . $id . $value . $class_names .'>';

        $attributes  = ! empty( $item->attr_title ) ? ' title="'  . esc_attr( $item->attr_title ) .'"' : '';
        $attributes .= ! empty( $item->target )     ? ' target="' . esc_attr( $item->target     ) .'"' : '';
        $attributes .= ! empty( $item->xfn )        ? ' rel="'    . esc_attr( $item->xfn        ) .'"' : '';

        //ADD YOUR PHP HERE TO DETERMINE WHATEVER IT IS YOU NEED FOR YOUR LINK
        $addedStuff = 'some added stuff to append to your URL';
        $attributes .= ! empty( $item->url )        ? ' href="'   . esc_attr( $item->url.$addedStuff) .'"' : '';
        ////////////////////

        $item_output = $args->before;
        $item_output .= '<a'. $attributes .'>';
        $item_output .= $args->link_before . apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID ) . $args->link_after;
        $item_output .= '</a>';
        $item_output .= $args->after;

        $output .= apply_filters( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args );
    }
}
```

I'm not sure what it is you want to add to the URL, but this should get you started in modifying things. Once you're done making the URL look however you want, you need to adjust your call to [WP Nav Menu](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu) to add the new Walker class to any existing arguments:

```
wp_nav_menu(array('walker' => new Query_Nav()));
```

More documentation on Nav Walkers Here:

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/14037/menu-items-description-custom-walker-for-wp-nav-menu/14039#14039
http://www.kriesi.at/archives/improve-your-wordpress-navigation-menu-output